# User has denied permisssion in Ionic 4 SMS cordova

Tags: android, cordova, ionic-framework, npm, ionic4

I am using Ionic 4 to build an app that is meant to send an emergency SMS, therefore I need it to be sent programatically without entering into the native SMS app.

Im using the following code:

```
async sendSMS(){
this.androidPermissions.checkPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.SEND_SMS).then(
  result => console.log('Has permission?'+result.hasPermission),
  err => this.androidPermissions.requestPermission(this.androidPermissions.PERMISSION.SEND_SMS )
  );
var options = {
        replaceLineBreaks: true, // true to replace \n by a new line, false by default
        android: {
            //intent: 'INTENT'  // send SMS with the native android SMS messaging
           intent: '' // send SMS without opening any other app
        }
    };
    try{
    await this.sms.send(this.phoneNumber.toString(),this.textMessage,options);
    console.log("sent");
    this.mostrarToast("mensage sent");
  }
  catch(e){
    console.log(JSON.stringify(e));
    console.log(e);
    this.mostrarToast(e);
  }
```

When i open my logcat I get this:

```
2019-03-19 21:17:12.255 11786-11786/io.ionic.starter I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(168)] "Has permission?", source: http://localhost:8080/home-home-module.js (168)
2019-03-19 21:17:12.322 11786-11786/io.ionic.starter I/chromium: [INFO:CONSOLE(187)] ""User has denied permission"", source: http://localhost:8080/home-home-module.js (187)
2019-03-19 21:17:12.322 11786-11786/io.ionic.starter I/chromium [INFO:CONSOLE(188)] "User has denied permission", source: http://localhost:8080/home-home-module.js (188)
```

Anyone knows why I cant send the message?

Answer (score 10, accepted):

Add this on your Android Manifest first

```
<uses-permission android:name="android.permission.SEND_SMS"/>
```

Comment: Are you using this library? https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/android-permissions

Comment: I believe I have touched this before. Android recently updated the way permissions work wherein you can ask a specific permission once you needed it.